# Why isnt my $().css({ "visibility": "visible"}) working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

I can't seem to get my jquery `<div id="NotificationDotOnNav" > {{NotificationNavDot}} </div>` function to work!

Find below the helper file:

```
<template name="home">
    <div id="NotificationDotOnNav" > {{NotificationNavDot}} </div>
</template>
```

Find below my helper file:

```
Template.home.helpers({

  'NotificationNavDot': function () {

     var numberOfNotifications = recipientsDetails.find({counts:1}).count();

     if (numberOfNotifications > 0) {

           $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css({ "visibility": "visible"});
           alert("Testing!");

           return;
        }

     else { 

           $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css({ "visibility": "hidden"});       

        }           

     },
});
```

When run, a popup with `Testing!` displays, clearly meaning the flow actually enters the `if (numberOfNotifications > 0)`, however the `$("#NotificationDotOnNav").css({ "visibility": "visible"});` fails to fire up!

What I find very strange is that, when copy & paste and run:  `$("#NotificationDotOnNav").css({ "visibility": "visible"});` in the browser console, it works!

Can someone kindly explain why it only fires-up when run in the browser console and not otherwise? Also kindly help me get this simple code to work.

I have included the relevant CSS file, in case this will help

```
#NotificationDotOnNav{
top: 10px;
float: right;
right: 5%; 
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
min-width: 10px;
padding: 7px 7px;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #f54555ad; 
}
```

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: How often and when is this function called? create a working example to demonstrate the issue. Assuming your function works correctly, then the issue might be 1) function called too early dom is not ready so the css line does nothing 2) function called multiple times and the last time it is called, it hides the element

Comment: Is the dom element already existing at that time you try to make the call? Replace with console.log($("#NotificationDotOnNav")[0]); for testing...

Comment: Can you put it in codepen or anywhere else?

Comment: @SirBT Your function is invoked before the `#NotificationDotOnNav` element is even rendered on the DOM.

Comment: Presumably the element `#NotificationDotOnNav` exists, and you don't have a typo in the name? Does `console.log(document.getElementById('NotificationDotOnNav'))` log the correct element?

Comment: @DavidThomas Nope no typo in the name at all. And yes the console.log(document.getElementById('NotificationDotOnNav')) prints out the correct element name.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your helper function execute after the Document Object Model (DOM) is ready and becomes safe to manipulate (this could be the reasons why your code runs when you type it in dev console but not when your run your js).

You can use `$( document ).ready( handler )` ([doc](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)) for that.

Please consider a minimal reproducible example so we can help you out with more details.

By the way, you could also improve your code by caching the selector and using a ternary to write it more succinctly:

```
...
const numberOfNotifications = recipientsDetails.find({counts:1}).count();
const elm = $("#NotificationDotOnNav") // query the DOM just once
numberOfNotifications > 0 ? elm.show() : elm.hide()

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Template.home.helpers({

 'NotificationNavDot': function () {

  var numberOfNotifications = recipientsDetails.find({counts:1}).count();

     if (numberOfNotifications > 0) {
        $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css('opacity', '1');
        alert("Testing!");
        return;
     } else { 
       $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css('opacity', '0');       
     }           
 }
});
```

Also change your CSS code:

```
#NotificationDotOnNav {
 top: 10px;
 float: right;
 right: 5%; 
 opacity: 0;  /* this has been changed */ 
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 min-width: 10px;
 padding: 7px 7px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #f54555ad; 
}
```

Comment: But how does this help? What problem does it solve? It has the problem that the element will now be hidden, and its space in the layout, will be removed which may affect (adversely or otherwise) the layout of the page.

Comment: You're right. In this case just try it with opacity: 1; (to show) and opacity: 0; (to hide)

Comment: @Tipe thanks for your suggested solution, I've tried it out just like you suggested, but your suggestion bore no effect what so ever. Though the "Testing!" pops up, the  "#NotificationDotOnNav" doesnt show at all. Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: @Tipe the strange thing still remains that this works only when I run: $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css('opacity', '1'); in the browser console!

Answer (score 0):

I found a walk around the issue that works.

Find below the changes that I've made to enable the code to work.

Find below updates I've made to my HTML code:

```
<template name="home">
    <span id="NotificationDotOnNav" class="badge animated"> {{NotificationNavDot}} </span>
</template>
```

Find below my helper file:

```
Template.home.helpers({

   'NotificationNavDot': function () {
        var numberOfNotifications = recipientsDetails.find({counts:1}).count();

        if (numberOfNotifications > 0 ) {

               $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css({"visibility": "visible"});

               return 0;
            }

        else {  

               $("#NotificationDotOnNav").css({ "visibility": "hidden"});

            }           

    }

});
```

Find below my CSS:

```
#NotificationDotOnNav{
top: 11px;
float: right;
right: 10%;
height: 13px;
width: 1px;
position: fixed;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 9;
font-size: xx-small;
color: #f5455500;
background-color: #f54555b5;    
}
```

Nevertheless Id like to thank everyone for their contributions.